# I want to run a shell command(mongorestore and mongoexport) from a php file. Mongo is running in the background

Tags: php, mongodb, shell, csv

```html
<html>
<body>
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
  if($con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','mooc'))
  {
   $filetemp = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
   $filename = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
   $filetype = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'];
  
   $filepath = "csvfiles/".$filename;
   $m=new MongoDB\Driver\Manager();
//
//   echo "Connected to database successfully.";
 //  $db=$m->test;
//   echo "database selected";

   
   

   //echo "enter";
   //echo shell_exec("python C:/xampp/Xampp/htdocs/csvseparator.py 2>&1");
   //echo "left";
   $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   $file1=explode(".",$filename);
   $ext=$file1[1];
   $allowed=array("bson");
   if(in_array($ext,$allowed))
   {
    move_uploaded_file($filetemp,$filepath);
    $query = "INSERT INTO csv(name,path,type,ip) VALUES('$filename','$filepath','$filetype','$ip')";
    $ros = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    echo "file uploaded";
    //echo shell_exec("mongorestore -d admin -c contents /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/production/csvfiles/contents.bson --port 27017 -u 'admin' -p 'admin123' --authenticationDatabase 'admin' 2>&1");

    //echo shell_exec("mongoexport --db admin --collection contents --fields _id,_type,abuse_flaggers,anonymous,anonymous_to_peers,at_position_list,author_id,author_username,body,closed,comment_count,comment_thread,commentable_id,course_id,created_at,endorsed,historical_abuse,last_activity_at,parent_id,parents_id,sk,thread_type,title,updated_at,visible,votes --out /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/production/csvfiles/out.csv --port 27017 -u 'admin' -p 'admin123' --authenticationDatabase 'admin' 2>&1");

    

   }
   else
   {
    echo "Upload only Bson file";
    echo "<br />";
    echo '<a href="upload1.php">Click here</a> to go back and try again';
   }
   
  }
 }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

These are my shell commands :

```
mongorestore -d admin -c contents /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/production/csvfiles/contents.bson --port 27017 -u 'admin' -p 'admin123' --authenticationDatabase 'admin'

mongoexport --db admin --collection contents --fields _id,_type,abuse_flaggers,anonymous,anonymous_to_peers,at_position_list,author_id,author_username,body,closed,comment_count,comment_thread,commentable_id,course_id,created_at,endorsed,historical_abuse,last_activity_at,parent_id,parents_id,sk,thread_type,title,updated_at,visible,votes --out /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/production/csvfiles/out.csv --port 27017 -u 'admin' -p 'admin123' --authenticationDatabase 'admin'
```

How do i get over this issue?

When I use `2>&1` along with the commands, it gives me an error as:

> mongorestore: relocation error: mongorestore: symbol X509_NAME_free, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.0.0 with link time reference

and

> mongoexport: relocation error: mongoexport: symbol X509_NAME_free, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.0.0 with link time reference

P.S: When I run the two mongo commands from my cmd window, I get the output as expected.

The commands read a bson file and output its content into a csv file and creates a new csv file.
I have attached my php file.
Please help me!

Comment: Are you trying to set these commands in cron? Which os it this?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Are you trying to run them from .php file?

Comment: yes i am running those commands from a php file